# How can I handle a form's close event from within a *different* form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

(Using VB.NET 2010)

Let's say I have 2 forms, named Form1 and Form2.

Is it possible to handle Form2's close event from a sub inside Form1? For example, I'd like to do something like this inside the Form1 class...

```
    Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Form2.FormClosed

        ' Code to run when Form2 is closed

    End Sub
```

But obviously, that doesn't work.

So... any way to do this? Or, any workaround to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that. Won't do it again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to declare a variable with the WithEvents keyword:

```
Dim WithEvents popup As Form2
```

And create the form similar to this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    popup = New Form2
    popup.Show()
End Sub
```

Now your event handler will work just fine.